# Why am I getting unbound variable i bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following script which works for the most part till it hits a specific line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

# Go Home.
cd /vagrant/Freya/

CLEANED_ASSETS=false

## Clean up time!
## Remove all vendor and composer.lock folders - just because.
for f in *; do
  if [[ -d $f ]]; then
    if [[ $f != ".git" ]] && [[ $f != "bin" ]] && [[ $f != "docs" ]]; then

      if [[ $f == "Loader" ]] && [[ $CLEANED_ASSETS == false ]]; then
        cd "$f/"
        if [[ -d "Assets" ]]; then
          cd Assets/
          rm -rf vendor composer.lock docs
          let $CLEANED_ASSETS=true
          cd ../../
        fi
      fi

      cd "$f/"
      rm -rf vendor composer.lock docs
      cd ../
    fi
  fi
done
```

The issue is when it hits `let $CLEANED_ASSETS=true` I am not sure the proper way to set this variable to true, so it never enters this loop again. I keep getting:

```
+ let false=true
bin/clean-directories: line 21: true: unbound variable
```

Comment: It should just be `CLEANED_ASSETS=true`. No `let`, no `$`.

Comment: ...even better, don't use the strings `true` and `false` at all, but instead use the numeric values `1` and `0`. Then you can efficiently say `if (( cleaned_assets )); then ...`.

Comment: ...also, don't use all-caps variable names -- by convention, these are reserved for environment variables and builtins; avoiding them prevents you from overwriting variables in one of those classes by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CLEANED_ASSETS=true
```

No `let`, no `$`.

In particular, the `let` causes `true` to be treated as a variable name (searched for a numeric value), and referring to variable names that don't exist gets you flagged by `set -u`.